# bash read file line by line and use lines as arguments

Tags: bash

I have a file 'list' with a list of archives that I want to unpack. My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
   echo 'string has been read'
   grep -e '**.zip' | xargs -d '\n' unzip -o
done < 'list'
```

But it works only for first zip-archive in a list and ignores other strings in list. If I comment out the `'grep -e '**.zip' | xargs -d '\n' unzip -o'` script reads all lines.

I can't understand why it works this way, and how to fix it.

Comment: As for what's actually happening here, the `grep` command will consume the rest of the lines from `list`.  You're not telling it where to read from, so it is reading standard input, which is redirected to come from your file.  Of course, `grep -e '**.zip'` passes the matches from the file except the first one to `xargs`, so it's really not doing what you think it's doing.  (Note also that the regex is invalid; it might return no matches, or all lines, or lines which somehow match the valid part of the regex.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not refering to `$line` in your loop. Hence it wont work the way you want.

What about:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ "\.zip$" ]]; then
        unzip -o $line
    fi
done < list
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But list contains 7z and tar archives, so i'd want to unzip only zip-archives.

Comment: While the regex is valid, it means 'any character followed by "zip"'.  So theoretically you could get a false positive on, say, a file named `unix.gzip`.  The proper regex is `\.zip$`.

Answer (score 3):

Could be done even without a loop, I think.

```
grep '\.zip$' < yourfile.txt | xargs -n1 unzip -o
```

or, from stdin:

```
grep '\.zip$' | xargs -n1 unzip -o
```

The -n1 tells xargs to use 1 command line per argument